# Entity Framework 7 Navigation Relationships Object References Not Set to Instance of Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have created a database in sqlserver 2014. I am using entity framework 7 and I have reversed engineered the database in code via dmx ef scaffolding command.

Things seem good until i try and access a navigation property. All relationship object are coming up null and are giving me the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. There is dummy data in the database so it seems that the properties that reference other objects never get instantiated.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Poco's:

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}

public partial class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        OrderLineItems = new HashSet<OrderLineItems>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLineItems> OrderLineItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public partial class DemoContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Items>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Active).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.Cost).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(60);

            entity.Property(e => e.Number)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            entity.Property(e => e.Price).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.Sku).HasMaxLength(30);

            entity.Property(e => e.Upc).HasMaxLength(30);

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasColumnType("datetime");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLineItems>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Active).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Item).WithMany(p => p.OrderLineItems).HasForeignKey(d => d.ItemId);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Order).WithMany(p => p.OrderLineItems).HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Active).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.Address)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(45);

            entity.Property(e => e.City)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(45);

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            entity.Property(e => e.State)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(45);

            entity.Property(e => e.SubTotal).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.Tax).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.Total).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Zip)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(9)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Orders).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Active).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.BirthDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(40);

            entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(40);

            entity.Property(e => e.Password)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(60);

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Username)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(40);
        });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Items> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderLineItems> OrderLineItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Executed Code:

```
var db = new DemoContext();
var orders = db.Orders.ToList();
var model = orders[0].User;
return View(model);
```

I get null for the user property on the order. Any Ideas???

Comment: `db.Orders.Include(o => o.User).ToList()`

Comment: Lazy loading isn't implemented yet, so you have to Include the user.

Comment: Thank you. @CodeCaster. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i have had that issue before
U can Remove the

```
  Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
```

And set

```
  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

in the context constructor for lazy loading, with that you dont need the .include(.............)